# Why the limit $\rho_2(i,-i)=0$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Why the limit $\rho_2(i,-i)=0$?

Comment: I suppose the book is giving an example of two equivalent metrics (even complete metrics)  that do not have the same set of Cauchy sequences. (Although equivalent metrics must have the same set of $convergent$ sequences, because in a metric space $S,$ the set of convergent sequences, and the closure operator on subsets of $S,$   completely determine each  other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $y\in S^1$ \ $\{(0,1)\}$ there is  a unique $T(y)\in (-3\pi/2, \pi/2)$ such that $y=(\cos T(y),\sin T(y)).$

And $T: S^1$ \ $\{(0,1)\}\to (-3\pi /2, \pi /2)$ is a homeomorphism. So the composite function $(Th):\Bbb R \to (-3\pi/2,\pi /2)$ is a homeomorphism.

Consider any homeomorphism $H: \Bbb R \to (a,b)$ to a bounded  real interval $(a,b).$ Now $H$ must be  monotonic because it is  continuous and injective.  We must have either

(I).  $ \lim_{i\to \infty} H(i)=a$ and $\lim_{i\to -\infty} H(i)=b,$... or

(II).  $ \lim_{i\to \infty}H(i)=b$ and $\lim_{i\to -\infty}H(i)=a.$

If neither (I) nor (II) held then the monotonicity of  $H$ would imply that $H$ is not surjective onto $(a,b)$.

Apply this with $H=Tf$ and $(a,b)=(-3\pi /2,\pi /2).$

Comment: every good explanation! thanks very much

Comment: In your answer, is the topology of $(-3\pi/2,\pi/2)$ equipped with the subspace of $R$?

Comment: Yes. The "usual", or "standard" topology on $(-3\pi /2,\pi /2).$

Comment: Yes....................

Answer (score 4):

Note that since $h:\mathbb{R}\to S^1\backslash\{(0,1)\}$ is a homeomorphism then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)=(0,1)=\lim_{x\to\infty} h(-x)$$

And since $\rho$ is continuous with respect to the Euclidean (natural) metric then the thesis easily follows by simple evaluation:

$$\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} \rho_2(-i, i)=\lim\rho\big(h(-i), h(i)\big)=$$
$$=\rho\bigg(\lim \big(h(-i), h(i)\big)\bigg)=$$
$$=\rho\big(\lim h(-i), \lim h(i)\big)=$$
$$=\rho\big((0,1), (0,1)\big)=0.$$

Comment: I still don't understand the first equation that why $\lim h(x)$ and $h(-x)$ must be $(0,1)$? Is there a specific proof for this? thanks